# Normalized space in xslt

Tags: xslt

While we use Normalized Space in xslt the child elements/ tags are automatically removed. If I want to not remove a particular child tag then what should I use?

Code:

> ```
> <mixed-citation publication-type="book">
> <collab>Panel on Antiretroviral Guidelines for Adults and Adolescents</collab>
> . 
> <source>
> Guidelines for the use of antiretroviral agents in HIV-1-infected adults and adolescents
> </source>
> . 
> <publisher-loc>Rockville, MD</publisher-loc>
>  : 
> <publisher-name>US Department of Health and Human Services (DHHS)</publisher-name>; May 
> <year>2014</year> [regularly updated]. [
> <uri xlink:href="http://aidsinfo.nih.gov/guidelines/html/1/adult-and-adolescent-arv-guidelines/0">URL</uri>]
> </mixed-citation>
> </ref>
> ```

XSLT Code :

```
<xsl:template match = "mixed-citation">
<xsl:element name = "p">
<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

In the above code I want to print all the text values and remove all the tags except < uri> tag. Please help !!!

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the XSLT you currently have. The problem is probably not with `normalize-space()` itself, but how you are using it. Thank you.

Comment: You need to edit your question to include the code, as code is hard to read in comments. Also, can you edit your question to show your expected output. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to skip descendant elements and copy a certain one then you have two options, use `xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"` as the default and then write a template for `uri` elements to be copied:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>

  <xsl:template match="mixed-citation">
      <p>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </p>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="mixed-citation//text()">
      <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="mixed-citation//uri">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiZQaFi

or use `shallow-copy` as the default and then make sure you override it for the `descendants` other than `uri`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="mixed-citation">
      <p>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </p>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="mixed-citation//text()">
      <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="mixed-citation//*[not(self::uri)]">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiZQaFi/1

If you are using earlier versions then the current version 3 of XSLT then see https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#built-in-templates-shallow-skip on how the used `xsl:mode` declarations translate into templates e.g. instead of

```
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>
```

you can use

```
  <xsl:template match="*"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>
```

and the `shallow-copy` translates into the well-known identity transformation template.

Comment: I am using XSLT 2.0 version. I think the above code is not compatible with v2.0

Comment: @binodkumar, see the edit, the use of  `xsl:mode` is not relevant for the solution, just a more compact and convenient syntax you can as well express with templates. Note also that the current releases of the main XSLT 2 implementations like Saxon 9 or Altova Raptor have been updated to support XSLT 3.